# Eonasdan bootstrap datetimepicker not setting initial value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, eonasdan-datetimepicker

For date of birth field, date time picker is not picking up the value sent by the asp.net MVC server side, instead it is loading up the clients local time. How to make date time picker to initialize itself with the date sent from the server?

[image]

Above image shows the initialisation of the datetimepicker.

[image]

Above image shows the field declared in the view model with required validation attributes.

[image]

Above image shows the picker taking the clients time instead of the actual value of the input sent by the mvc server side.

[image]
Above image shows the actual value sent by the server is 1/2/2017,but still date time picker is showing the current date of the client side

Answer (score 1):

use "date" method

```
$("{your datetimepicker ID}").data('DateTimePicker').date({newDate});
```

Remember to use ID in jquery selector.

If you need more information, you can read on its manual page, [here](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Functions/#date)